# Combine two number columns but exclude zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe from a database download that I cleaned up a bit. Unfortunately some of the single numbers split into a second column (row 9) from a single one. I'm trying to merge the two columns but exclude the zero values.

```
               city  crashes  crashes_1  total_crashes
1          ABERDEEN      710          0            710
2      ACHERS LODGE        1          0              1
3              ACME        1          0              1
4           ADVANCE       55          0             55
5             AFTON        2          0              2
6           AHOSKIE      393          0            393
7      AKERS CENTER        1          0              1
8          ALAMANCE       50          0             50
9         ALBEMARLE        1         58             59
```

So for row 9 I want to end with:

```
9         ALBEMARLE        1         58            158
```

I tried a few snippets but nothing seems to work:

```
df['total_crashes'] = df['crashes'].astype(str).str.zfill(0) + df['crashes_1'].astype(str).str.zfill(0)

df['total_crashes'] = df['total_crashes'].astype(str).replace('\0', '', regex=True)

df['total_crashes'] = df['total_crashes'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x[x!=0]))

df['total_crashes'] = df['total_crashes'].str.cat(df['total_crashes'], x[x!=0])

df['total_crashes'] = df.drop[0].sum(axis=1)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the expected output for row #8?

Comment: Got my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where` condition:

```
df['total_crashes'] = df['crashes'].astype(str) + df['crashes_1'].astype(str).where(df['crashes_1'] != 0, "")
```

Comment: Thank you Quang! The where condition was what I needed. This issue is solved.